# Predict outcome based on user input with Neural Network

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I have wrote a code for simple `neural network` in `Python`. Neural network uses `Sigmoid` function to predict outcome (0 or 1).
My question is, how can I predict outcome based on my own input?

For example, I want to make prediction for these input values:

```
input 1: 0.3
input 2: -0.1
input 3: 0.1

my_input = [0.3, -0.1, 0.1]
```

Where should I pass this parameters / inputs?
This is the code that I have:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'input 1':[0.5, 0.3, 0, 0.1, 0.4, -0.4, 0.4, 0.1, -0.6, 0.2, 0.6, 0, 0.2, 0.2, -0.1, -0.1, 0, 0.4, -0.2, -0.4],
                   'input 2':[0.3, 0.6, -0.4, -0.2, 0.9, 0, 0.35, -0.4, -0.9, 0.4, 0.3, -0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3],
                   'input 3':[0, 0.4, 0, -0.1, 0.4, -0.2, 0.7, -0.3, -0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0, 0.5, 0.4, -0.31, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2],
                   'result':[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]})

print(df)

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_derivate(x):
    return x * (1 - x)


features = df.iloc[:,:-1].to_numpy()
results =  df.iloc[:,-1:].to_numpy()

np.random.seed(1)

weights = 2 * np.random.random((3,1)) - 1

print('These are my random weights:\n')
print(weights)

for iteration in range(100000):

    input_layer = features

    outputs = sigmoid(np.dot(input_layer, weights))
    error = results - outputs
    adjustments = error * sigmoid_derivate(outputs)
    weights += np.dot(input_layer.T, adjustments)


df['output prediction'] = outputs.round(0)
print(df)
```

So, output should be only one value, zero or one.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What are `input1, input2, input3`? Are they training samples?

Comment: Isn't `user_input = input()` and then `outputs = sigmoid(np.dot(user_input, weights))` enough?

Comment: @Raj, those are the features, look at my code, check out dataframe thats used for training.

Comment: @emremrah and in `input=()` should put my features, so it should look like this: user_input = input(input1, input2, input3) ?

Comment: You can get your inputs seperated by a character (say `,`), then parse them to make a list or `np.array` (`input_list = user_input.split(',')` or `np.array(user_input.split(','))` if you want it as array), lastly use it as `outputs = sigmoid(np.dot(input_list, weights))`

Comment: Because you are using CLI I assume you are going to pass one input at a time. If not, I think it's not usable enouth, maybe reading the input from a file would be nice.

Comment: I just wrote an answer, you can check it out.

Comment: @emremrah Im not importing one value at the time, I wanted to pass a dataframe, or array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your prediction is by the same method as during training:

```
my_output = sigmoid(np.dot(my_input, weights))
```

If you try using as input the first three examples of your training you will find correct outputs :

```
my_input = [0.3,-0.1,0.1]
prediction: [1.]
my_input = [0.5,.3,0]
prediction: [1.]
my_input = [0.0,-.4,0.0]
prediction: [2.25648121e-13]
```

congratulations that you implemented your own training!

Comment: OK, but I have one question...If I add my_input instead of input_layer in for loop that I have , and values in my_input are new values (values that are not in my training data, not in my df) then what data will be used for training? 
Thats the part that I do not understand....

If input_layer = features are my training data, and now i put my_input instead of features, will that ruin my training?

Comment: You can first train using the values in the df, and then do predictions based on the my_input new values. Alternatively use my_input values and train on those - but you need the 'correct answers' e.g. the 'result' column of the df, if you don't have that info for my_input then you must use the df. The 'result' column is required in training.

Comment: Is it correct if I put my code in for loop, that for loop is for number of iterations (for example [1000,3000, 5000,7000,10000]). And then, I save number of iterations that gives me the best accuracy based on `error = results - outputs`, and then I run `sigmoid(np.dot(my_input, weights))` for checking output based on my input?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by:

```py
# in addition to your previous code
In [14]: while True: 
    ...:     user_input = input("Enter the input: ") 
    ...:     user_input = [float(number) for number in user_input.split(',')] 
    ...:     outputs = sigmoid(np.dot(user_input, weights)) 
    ...:     print("Outputs:",outputs) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Enter the input: 0.6,0.1,0.9
Outputs: [1.]
Enter the input:
```

This will:

1. ask for an input one at a time
2. because input will being get as string, it will parse it and convert the numbers to float
3. then will do the calculations
4. then ask for another.